# dpkg: need an action option

Tags: linux, google-chrome, backtrack-linux

[image]Installing Google Chrome On Backtrack 5r3

but i m getting error **dpkg: need an action option**

```
root@bt:~# ls
Desktop  google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
root@bt:~# dpkg .i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
dpkg: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
Type dpkg --license for copyright license and lack of warranty (GNU GPL) [*].

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
root@bt:~# dpkg .i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
dpkg: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
Type dpkg --license for copyright license and lack of warranty (GNU GPL) [*].

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
root@bt:~#
```

**now this error**

```
root@bt:~# dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 266492 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace google-chrome-stable 33.0.1750.152-1 (using google-chrome-    stable_current_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement google-chrome-stable ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
google-chrome-stable depends on gconf-service; however:
  Package gconf-service is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libasound2 (>= 1.0.23); however:
  Version of libasound2 on system is 1.0.22-0ubuntu7.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
  Version of libgcrypt11 on system is 1.4.4-5ubuntu2.1.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Version of libgtk2.0-0 on system is 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnspr4 (>= 1.8.0.10); however:
  Package libnspr4 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnss3 (>= 3.14.3); however:
  Package libnss3 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1); however:
  Version of libx11-6 on system is 2:1.3.2-1ubuntu3.
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.utf8.cache...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use following:

```
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Notice the "-" infront of the parameter i.

Comment: Above solution should resolve "dpkg: need an action option" issue. What is the new error you get?

Comment: New issues is due to missing dependencies. first execute "sudo apt-get install -f". then run "dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb". First command will try to resolve missing dependencies.

Comment: i have now installed but its not launching :(   pls check the attached screenshot.... wht went wrong now :( :(

Answer (score 45):

This error can occur when copy/pasting the command from online instructions rather than typing it yourself. So instead of '-' you end up with '–' and you get the error.

Answer (score 9):

I had this error even using **-i**. Then I tried using **--install** and it worked.

> sudo dpkg --install google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb

Answer (score 2):

please correct your command `dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb` ,You need to provide -i instead of .i option

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same problem when following a tutorial on how to install chrome. The problem was that I was copying a different character set from the tutorial which caused confusion in the hyphen from the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems  different representation of characters when you "copy and paste". Copying and pasting will yield "xxx **–i** xxxx"... but what your terminal requires is "**-i**". The first one is a longer 'dash'  ie "**–**", while the second (correct) one is a shorter dash ie "**-**". This discrepancy causes the error. To avoid, just replace the dash aspect by typing directly from your keyboard. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

re-dependency problem maybe it's because of "gnupg is not installed".